# Adding Post to wordpress from external source, Working in Chrome, not in IE

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I've created a script which creates new posts in wordpress from an external source. This works in Google Chrome but not in internet explorer, edge etc.

```
    <?php

session_start();

$content = $_SESSION['body'];
$title = $_SESSION['title']; 
$user_id = 2;

// Load WordPress
require_once './wp-load.php';
require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php';
// Set the timezone so times are calculated correctly
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
// Create post
$id = wp_insert_post(array(
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_content'  => $content,
    'post_date'     => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_author'   => $user_id,
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post_status'   => 'draft',
));
if ($id) {
    // Set category - create if it doesn't exist yet
    wp_set_post_terms($id, wp_create_category('Bulletins'), 'category');
    // Add meta data, if required
    add_post_meta($id, 'meta_key', $metadata);
    echo "Success!";

} else {
    echo "WARNING: Failed to insert post into WordPress\n";
}

?>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why it won't work in IE?

Answer (score 1):

The error message might help here!

The only thing that I can see client-side that could possibly be affecting this server-side code would be your session state.

A couple questions: is there a previous page that redirects to this page? The code references 2 session variables that would have already been assigned.

Is it possible that you have an existing session in Chrome where these variables have already been assigned? If you attempt to browse to the page via Chrome in 'Incognito mode' do you get the error there?

(Rep too low to post a comment)

Comment: testing in chrome incognito mode shows the same error, there is a previous page where the user confirms the post details before they click Submit, which brings them here

Comment: Are you testing *from* the previous page? For example, in Chrome incognito mode if you go to the previous page and submit, do you still get the same error? Still sounds like a session problem to me.

Comment: It looks like it was a session problem. I moved the code to the previous page and had it execute there rather than on a separate page. that resolved the issue. the second page wasn't strictly necessary. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was caused by an error with the session not being passed correctly. having the code run on the previous page without passing the session resolved the issue.